# is mathematical operation valid in firebase firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have `capacity` as a field in my document. I want the user to decrease the capacity one by one. so I want to prevent malicious user to make capacity to be 0 directly

```
 match /events/{eventID} {            
   allow update: if isValidUpdate()    
}

function isValidUpdate() {
   return incomingData().capacity == existingData().capacity - 1
}

function existingData() {
    // Data that exists on the Firestore document
  return resource.data;
}

function incomingData() {
    // Data that is sent to a Firestore document
  return request.resource.data;
}
```

I have tried, but I can't find mathematical operation like + - * / for security rules in the documentation or from video tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbd_4LT0Y4s

is `incomingData().capacity == existingData().capacity - 1` a valid rules ? because I need a lot of mathematical operation to be applied

Comment: Yes, mathematical operations are valid on numerical values. Are your rules not working? If so, is `capacity` stored as a number?

Comment: Hello, are you still presenting this issue or were you able to fix it?